# Super simple js Countdown timer on android?

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

Im working on an app for android and i need a super simple javascript countdown timer
that can count hours, minutes and seconds.
If anyone want to share some code ill be happy.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out, its very simple jquery countdown.

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Or if you dont want jquery try this one

http://countdownjs.org/

Comment: You are welcome, if this answers your question please mark it as answered.